# How to get rid of extraneous (0..) in iteration when its not used?

Tags: rust, iterator

I came up with the [following function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd81dae3b8811b6a2d470853e9364a82) to transpose a `Vec<Vec<T>>`:

```rust
fn transpose<T>(v: Vec<Vec<T>>) -> Vec<Vec<T>> {
    let mut xs = v.into_iter().map(|x| x.into_iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    (0..)
        .map_while(|_| xs.iter_mut().map(|x| x.next()).collect())
        .collect()
}
```

The values of `(0..)` are unused but anchors the iterator. I can put anything there. But can it be restructured to not have a useless iterator there?

Comment: If all you need is an endless iterator then you can use `std::iter::repeat(())`. Technically, `0..` will eventually stop producing items after it produces the value `i32::MAX`. (I doubt you'll have a vector with that many items, but with `repeat` you don't even have that problem theoretically, plus you're not wasting time counting an index you won't ever use.)

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, either of these work, but I'm looking for a way to remove it entirely because neither `(0..)` nor `repeat(())` serve a purpose. Unfortunately, I don't really see a way other than to have _something_ there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::iter::from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html):

> Creates a new iterator where each iteration calls the provided closure `F: FnMut() -> Option<T>`.

```
fn transpose<T>(v: Vec<Vec<T>>) -> Vec<Vec<T>> {
    let mut xs = v.into_iter().map(|x| x.into_iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    std::iter::from_fn(|| xs.iter_mut().map(|x| x.next()).collect()).collect()
}
```

Comment: Sweet, didn't think of that.